# Can you guess the word?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> *I have a pretty sharp memory.*
>
> *Preceded by a C, I am usually a hindrance.*
>
> *But with a B instead, I can prove to be the opposite of that.*
>
> *It might get difficult for you to identify me if you add an S though.*
>
> *But with an O, it should be fairly simple.*

Guess the word with the help of the above message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word is:

> **LOG**

*I have a pretty sharp memory.*

> A **log** is usually a record of events that have happened, e.g. within a computer system, a ship's journey records, or just a diary or journal.

*Preceded by a C, I am usually a hindrance.*

> A **CLOG** is a blockage, e.g. in a pipe, where the flow of water might be *hindered*.

*But with a B instead, I can prove to be the opposite of that.*

> A **BLOG** might be a useful way for a person to post their thoughts, ideas and worries, in a way that gives them headspace. Additionally, many blogs contain useful information for others looking for instructions or help online.

*It might get difficult for you to identify me if you add an S though.*

> Something that is a **SLOG** is *difficult* to get through...

*But with an O, it should be fairly simple.*

> Placing the 'O' this time at the end (since it doesn't specify where this should be positioned), a company **LOGO** is generally better for memorability when it is kept *simple*!

Comment: Nice, that was quick.

Comment: @ManishKundu Thanks - a nice little poser before starting my working day proper! Seems like it's been a while since we had wordplay-based riddles like this regularly on PSE...